# Extract time and day of the week from given datetime in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, datetime

I tried the `CONVERT(TIME,sample_datetime)`, but my software does not recognize TIME as a type.

How do I take sample `datetime` and extract the time from it in one variable and the day of the week from it in another variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

DATEPART or DATENAME with DW will work for the day of the week depending on which format you need

```
SELECT DATEPART(DW, GETDATE())
SELECT DATENAME(DW, GETDATE())
```

You can convert the datetime to a varchar with specific formatting to get just the time

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR, GETDATE(), 14)
```

2008 has a TIME datatype, but it doesn't sound like you're running that

Answer (score 2):

Using [DATEPART()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms174420.aspx) function:

```
// returns 4
SELECT DATEPART(day, '2010-09-04 11:22:33')

// returns 7
SELECT DATEPART(dw, '2010-09-04 11:22:33')

// returns 11:22:33
SELECT CAST(DATEPART(HOUR, '2010-09-04 11:22:33') AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':'
     + CAST(DATEPART(MINUTE, '2010-09-04 11:22:33') AS VARCHAR(2)) + ':'
     + CAST(DATEPART(SECOND, '2010-09-04 11:22:33')AS VARCHAR(2))
```

Regarding TIME data type - it introduced since Sql Server 2008:

```
SELECT CAST('2010-09-04 11:22:33'  as Time)
```

Answer (score 1):

you didnt specify sql server version but

`select datepart(dw,yourdate)` should do it.